# I want to upgrade to first class but the middle flight cannot be upgraded

Tags: luggage, international-travel, american-airlines, business-class

Right now I have a planned trip from Chicago to Colombia with stop in Miami in Main Cabin (American Airlines). I want to upgrade to business/first class but, it adds me one more stop in Atlanta. The problem is that, the flight from Chicago to Atlanta only has Main Cabin fare.

My question is

Can I make this upgrade and use the luggage benefits of the business class even with that middle stop in Main Cabin? (I'd check my bags in Chicago and receive them in Colombia -> The Miami - Colombia flight is business class).

Hope it is understandable. Thanks!

Comment: Did you call or email the airline and ask?

Comment: You should call the airlines. The extra stop makes no sense. And yes, you can use Business luggage all the way through even if one leg is downgraded.